# NestJS E2E Testing "TypeError: metatype is not a constructor"

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

I am trying to create a basic e2e test for one of the routes on my NestJS API. The route has no parameters or request needed, it is a simple GET request. I have an authentication guard `ATGuard` that I have implemented and am using globally in my `AppModule`:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        HealthModule
    ],
    providers: [

        {
            provide: APP_GUARD,
            useExisting: ATGuard,
        },
        ATGuard
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My e2e test:

```
describe("HealthController (e2e)", () => {
    let app: NestFastifyApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const mockAuthGuard: CanActivate = { canActivate: jest.fn(() => true) };

        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test
            .createTestingModule({
                imports: [AppModule],
            })
            .overrideProvider(ATGuard).useClass(mockAuthGuard)
            .compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication<NestFastifyApplication>(new FastifyAdapter());
        await app.init();
        await app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().ready();
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });

    it("/health (GET)", () => {
        return app
            .inject({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/health"
            })
            .then((result) => {
                expect(result.statusCode).toBe(200);
            });
    });
});
```

When I run the test I receive the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DncU8.png)

Before I was mocking the `ATGuard`, I was receiving a 401 response, which makes sense. I tried to mock the `ATGuard` with this code `.overrideGuard(ATGuard).useClass(mockAuthGuard)`.
I was still receiving a 401 though, so I changed it to use `.overrideProvider` as seen above.

After adding the mocked guard I am now receiving this error. My only thought of what's breaking is that the `ATGuard` class has 3 injected dependencies, but since I'm mocking the class as a whole, I would assume I don't need to mock the dependencies as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `useClass` to `useValue`. You are essentially passing an *instance* of the class already, so Nest can't run `new` on the object you pass. If you just use `useValue` instead, Nest will know not to try to call `new` and will just call `mock.canActivate` when the time is needed